# How to convert multiple tiffs image file into single image in angular9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf, npm

I am using Angular 9 to build a web application. I want to implement a functionality that will convert multiple Tiff images to a single PDF or window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) of pdf.

```
let images = ["http://netghost.narod.ru/gff/sample/images/tiff/ccitt_1.tif",
            http://netghost.narod.ru/gff/sample/images/tiff/ccitt_2.tif];
```

[For reference: I want to use something like this using tiff images files.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-pdf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I am not sure if you can achieve this merely on client-side since it's not renderable image format for browsers and that's what most libraries like [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) depends on (CMIIW). You can probably convert it to base64 string and put it into img tag, and create a new document from it and print/pdf it.

Comment: @choz Do you have a code for it?

Comment: Nope, you already have the reference for that jspdf. And there should be sample codes out there for tiff to base64.

Comment: This question looks like you just want someone to write the code for you - not cool on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche it not like that. I just want to understand how to write the merge functionality in angular

Comment: "Do you have a code for it?" - it is actually like that I think. How much research did you do before you asked this question here? You don't have any code, you're just asking for code that does this. I can't imagine you're the first to have this problem or that Google wouldn't turn up any hints on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not achievable client side.  No matter how you convert it (PNG, JPG, BASE64, etc), you'll never been able to merge images using javascript code.

There are a huge number of libraries for just about any backend language you could possibly use to do this task.  Some are free. Most are not free.

Here's a fully online solution.  I have zero experience with it, but it looks promising.  https://cloudconvert.com/api/v2